# Access obfuscated property

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to access a property which is not in the Interface of the current objecttype and has a encrypted name. You can see it in the following picture:
[image]

`context` is of Type `IDesignContext`

`IDesignContext` contains property `ActiveModelGraphics`. Now, in ActiveModelGraphics, there is the selected encrypted property. I am searching a way to access this property and enumerate the `IList`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The primary goal of obfuscation is to prevent you from doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could do what you need to, the process of obfuscation would be redundant. You would need a key, reference to the original code or some way of knowing what the data was pre-scrambling if you wanted to un-obfuscate it.